# Objective C: Releasing int/float properties

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, properties, floating-point, int

I'm having some trouble understanding something. I got a bunch of propeties in my app:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@property (readwrite) NSInteger buttonCount;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *soundSelected;
@property (readwrite) float fadeDecrease;
@property (readwrite) float fadeDelay;
```

These are obviously all synthesized in my .m file.
However, while audioPlayer and soundSelected are released fine in dealloc, the int buttonCount gives this warning:
"Invalid receiver type 'NSInteger'"
and the floats actually make the compiler cry with:
"Cannot convert to a pointer type"

Has this got something to do with the fact that they are not of object types and/or not retained?
Is it OK that they are not released?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`NSInteger`, like `float`, are not Objective-C types and do not follow the usual retain/release model. They're just primitives. Assigning values to the property will be sufficient.

```
@property (readwrite, assign) NSInteger buttonCount;
```

should be all you need.

`NSNumber` however does follow the usual retain/release cycle, so add attributes accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

> Has this got something to do with the
>   fact that they are not of object types
>   and/or not retained? Is it OK that they are not released?

Yes. You can only release objects that have a retain count. Primitive datatypes like int, float, and NSInteger do not need to be retained/released because they are not pointers referring to other parts of memory.

If you want to learn more about memory management, try taking a look at this documentation page:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1